# NSNumber cause app crash

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

I have a @property opacity in .h file

```
@property (assign) NSNumber *opacity;
```

Then in .m file I

```
@synthesize opacity;
```

Then in

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
```

I did

```
 opacity = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
```

When I run the app, Xcode shows this error

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code-EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

However, if I change that line to

```
opacity = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1];
```

Everything works fine.

Comment: why do you use assign? you should copy or retain the property

Comment: If your usig ARC you should use strong not retain.

Comment: Volker, I am using "Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X", the example in book uses @property (assign) float opacity; and does things in the setter part of opacity. I want to change that to key-value observing, so I changed that to NSNumber *opacity. I am new to this. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just looks like it works fine. But you have just covered that bug with an implementation detail of NSNumber.

As Volker pointed out you have a memory management problem. Your property should use `strong`. As in:

```
@property (strong) NSNumber *opacity;
```

And you should use that property when assigning values. e.g.:

```
self.opacity = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
```

So why does it work with `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]`? Because iOS tries to be smart. A integer 1 NSNumber is a singleton object which never gets deallocated. `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]` is not such an indestructible object, it will get deallocated once its reference count drops to zero. This happens after you leave the scope where the NSNumber instance was created, because it is never retained in your code.

You can see the singleton behaviour with this little logging code, which logs the pointer address of NSNumber instances:

```
NSLog(@"Address of `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]`: %p", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]);
NSLog(@"Address of `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]`: %p", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]);

NSLog(@"Address of `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]`: %p", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]);
NSLog(@"Address of `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]`: %p", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]);
```

which yields

```
Address of `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]`: 0x10c622d10
Address of `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]`: 0xb000000000000013
Address of `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]`: 0x10c129fb0
Address of `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]`: 0xb000000000000013
```

As you can see the two addresses from `numberWithFloat:1.0` differ, and the two addresses from `numberWithInteger:1` are the same. Because `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]` always returns the same object.

Comment: wow. great explanation. is there a resource for this kind of knowledge? as in "what happens under he hood of objective-c" kind of stuff?

Comment: @katzenhut when working with it for years this knowledge either is actively gathered or learned by incident ;)

Comment: Oh well, i guess ill just have to wait then ;)